# Rules for quantiles division

Tags: quantiles, quantile-regression

Generally speaking, are there any rules used to decide if it is better to use  quartiles, quintiles, deciles or percentiles when approaching a dataset for the purpose of quantile regression calculation?

I imagine that the larger the quantile division the highest the chance that probably the quantile regressions may get all scattered and cross each other.

Anyway I would be curious to hear both your opinions on the matter and/or links to papers or books that provide general rules or guidance for best practice.